# How to unlock locked tables in Williams Pinball Classics

Tags: williams-pinball-classics

I've just started playing Williams Pinball Classics for Xbox 360 (Release date: 17/06/2011). In the Arcade mode, I found a locked table named "Jive Time" in the Back Room. Are there any other unlockable tables in the game?

As far as I know, I need 100 credits to unlock a table in the game. At the moment, I have 130 credits but I can't unlock that table. When I select the table, there is only one option (B Button = Back). What do I need to do to unlock the table(s) in this game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 100 Credits is to unlock a game for **Free Play** mode. Free Play mode lets you play a table as many times as you want without spending any (additional) credits.

Tables can also be unlocked for Free Play by completing all five goals for any table.

---

**Jive Time** is the only table in the 360 version that needs to be unlocked before playing.

Unlocking it requires completing the **Williams Challenge** from the main menu. This challenge involves beating set high scores on the other 12 tables in one sitting. The order is as follows:

1. Gorgar - 100,000
2. Taxi - 1,000,000
3. Pinbot - 600,000
4. Funhouse - 2,500,000
5. Black Knight - 800,000
6. Space Shuttle - 1,000,000
7. Firepower - 200,000
8. Whirlwind - 2,000,000
9. Sorcerer - 500,000
10. Tales Of The Arabian Nights - 3,000,000
11. Medieval Madness - 15,000,000
12. No Good Gofers - 8,000,000

Some of these scores can be difficult to get consistently if you don't know the tables well, so it might be best to try completing the other tables' Basic Goals and unlocking Free Play on all of them before attempting the challenge.